# Call a local API from AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I want to call a local api from AWS lamdba (or any AWS tool that will do the job).  For example, given the following node api endpoint:

http://localhost:3334/api/ping

How can I wireup AWS to hit this?  Does the endpoint have to be publicly exposed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That endpoint is only available on the machine it is running on. There is no way anything outside that machine can hit it. An endpoint with an address of "localhost" can only be accessed from the local host.

You would have to expose your API to the internet, or setup some sort of [VPN link with your AWS VPC](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/VPC_VPN.html) in order to make your API accessible from AWS.